# dynamic navbar jquery addClass() not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a dynamic homepage which uses `switch` statements to change the content.

What I am trying to do is make the navbar get a `class="active"` when I'm on "that" page. I did search for a long time but I just couldn't get it to work.

My homepage.php:

```
<?php
include'inc/header.php';
include'inc/navbar.php';

if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
  switch ($_GET['page']) {
    default;
    include 'inc/pages/homepage.php';
    break;

    case 'inc/pages/homepage.php':
    include 'inc/pages/homepage.php';
    break;

    case 'inc/pages/page2.php':
    include 'inc/pages/page2.php';
    break;
    }
  }else{
    include 'inc/pages/homepage.php';
  }

include 'inc/footer.php';

?>
```

My navbar.php has this kind of links:

```
<nav>
    <a href="?page=inc/pages/homepage.php">Home</a>


    <a href="?page=inc/pages/page2.php">Pagina 2</a>
</nav>
```

I have tried this code (I did link the Jquery.min.js):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('nav a').click(function(){
            $('nav a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
         });
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this in PHP directly?

Comment: $('nav a').addClass("active"); use this instead of $(this).addClass("active");

Comment: That shouldn't really matter, he's inside the click()-function, $(this) will belong to whatever element he clicked on.

Comment: sorry i didnt notice that click event

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", 'nav a', function(){
    $('nav a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a link your browser loads a new page. So your JavaScript function is executed but then you load the new page where the JavaScript function did not get executed yet.

Try to check in `navbar.php` for the current page and add the class accordingly with php.

for example

```
<nav>
    <a href="/?page=inc/pages/homepage.php" class="<?php if ($_GET['page'] == 'inc/pages/homepage.php') echo " -active"; ?>">Home</a>
    ....
</nav>
```